# How to kill old parent processes?

Tags: c++, linux, pid

How do I kill old parent processes within a for loop? I have the following that forks a parent process

```
if (pid > 0){
    pid_t ppid = getppid();
    for (int parentid = ppid; parentid > 1; parentid++) {
        parentid = ppid;
        pid_t ppid = fork();
        if(ppid > 1) {
            execl("/usr/bin/elinks","elinks","google.com",(char *) NULL);
        }
        sleep(5);
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I have a child process continously running throughout

```
system("xdotool......")
```

I tried putting kill(ppid,SIGTERM) within the for loop but it was ignored. Only placing it after the loop does the kill signal but then the entire program quits. The parent forks keep stacking up and consuming ram so its necessary for me to kill the old parent when a new parent is created.

Comment: 1) It seems odd you're having your parent `exec` instead of the child. 2) `kill` is insufficient; you need to reap the terminated processes using something in the `wait` family or they'll stick around as zombies.

Comment: I've tried using execl on both the parent and child but getting the child to loop was difficult so I ended up using system() within a while(1) loop. I'll look into the wait call, thank you

Comment: it is unclear exactly what you are trying to do. First, you don't fork a parent. The normal paradigm is 'fork`/(child)`exec`, and as @StephenNewell said, `wait` for the child. Killing the parent is counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to make sure there is a proper termination condition for your 
for loop:

```
pid_t ppid = getppid();

for (int parentid = ppid; parentid > 1; parentid++) {

    parentid = ppid;

    pid_t ppid = fork();
```

Are you sure your for loop ends as you expect?

If parentid is always greater than 1 because fork() succeeded, how

does the loop terminate?

The fork function returns 0 to the child process, and the PID of the child to the parent process.

Therefore, you can use this code to determine whether the
code that is executing is the child or parent:

```
pid_t pid = fork();

if (pid == 0)
{
    /* At this point, the code that is executing is the child */
}
else if (pid > 0)
{
    /* At this point, the code that is executing is the parent */
}
else 
{
    /* The fork function call failed */
}
```

Your code needs to differentiate between the child and the
parent; you can use the exit system call in the block of
code above for the parent.

Comment: Once `execl` is hit in the parent, it'll never reach the `exit` call in the question.